# How to install the command WL

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3b+

I installed the utility wl  to enable some radio test:

sudo apt-get install wl

The added files are :

```
/var/lib/emacsen-common/state/installed/wl
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/remove/wl
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/compat/wl
/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/wl
/usr/share/pixmaps/wl
/usr/share/wl
/usr/share/wl/wl
/usr/share/doc/wl
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/wl
```

But when I want to use this command I have the error "command not found".

Comment: This'll be of help: https://wanderlust.github.io/wl-docs/wl.html#Start-Me-Up . After you perform those steps, just type (from **Emacs**) `M-x wl`

Comment: I think a bit of a mix-up (these two things are not the same, the emacs stuff is unrelated): https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wl_command ... `apt-file search "bin/wl"`  implies it is not available through Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `wl` is an emacs utility called WanderLust.

Ref https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WanderLust

However, if you need the broadcom wl utility for wifi testing, you are able to get this from the Raspberry Pi product information portal https://pip.raspberrypi.com/

You may need to sign an NDA